# Where are the print filters stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

I'm trying to backup my printer configuration to use it on another machine. To do this I copied the /etc/cups folder.

For some printers it says:

> There is a missing print filter for printer "PRINTER-NAME".

Where are the print filters located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr Filters are located in:

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter
```

Copy whatever you need in there and CUPS seems to pick it up automagically.

Comment: Properly installing CUPS should arguably install the pertinent files as well.

Comment: Hi @tripleee, Arguably yes, but even installing CUPS properly doesn’t mean CUPS works correctly on Ubuntu :(  [CUPS libgs load error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983970/where-does-cups-expect-to-find-libgs)